# Update jstilemap tilemap in spritekit/swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, jstilemap

I'm still pretty new with spritekit/jstilemap/programming in general.

I'm building a racing game with two tilemaps that scroll vertically with parralax. I was wondering if it's possible to update the tilemap without having to remove the current tilemap and create a new one?

This is basically what I'm doing now. Create two tilemaps:

```
for var i = 0; i < 2; i++
    {
        //tilemap
        var tileMap = JSTileMap(named: "map1.tmx")

        //size of tilemap
        var rect = tileMap.calculateAccumulatedFrame()
        tileMap.position = CGPoint(x: Int(rect.minX)/2, y: i*Int(rect.height))
        tileMap.name = "tilemap"
        self.addChild(tileMap)

    }
```

And in Update find nodes called tilemap. Move them down and bounce them up if they are low enough. Then if the map has been seen 4 times update the map with a new one by creating a whole new map and then delete the old one. This works but creates a hitch while the new map is loading.

```
        self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("tilemap") {
            node, stop in

            node.position = CGPointMake(node.position.x,node.position.y-8)



            if(node.position.y <= -node.calculateAccumulatedFrame().height) {

                    self.mapCount += 1



            if (self.mapCount <= 3) {

                // if map count is less than 3 just show the same map over and over

                node.position = CGPointMake(node.position.x, node.position.y+node.calculateAccumulatedFrame().height*2)



            } else if (self.mapCount == 5) {

                //update map if has been shown 4 times

                println("newTILE")

                var tileMap = JSTileMap(named: "map2.tmx")

                var rect = tileMap.calculateAccumulatedFrame()

                tileMap.position = CGPointMake(node.position.x, node.position.y+node.calculateAccumulatedFrame().height*2)

                tileMap.name = "tilemap"

                self.addChild(tileMap)


                //remove old map
                node.removeFromParent()



            } else if(self.mapCount >= 5) {



                node.position = CGPointMake(node.position.x, node.position.y+node.calculateAccumulatedFrame().height*2)



            }

      }
```